# Formatar valor javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola amigos estou com problema colocar os valores em real com javascript abaixo esta esta o codigo onde esta o valor preço  `preco = parseFloat (preco.replace(",",".") );`o valor fica R$ 60.90 com ponto, nesse outro formato `parseFloat (preco.replace(",","") );` ele fica assim R$ 6090 sem ponto e sem virgula, gostaria que ele ficasse assim: R$ 60,90 algum fera ai dar essa forca aqui

Comment: Depois do primeiro `preco` que tu colocou: `preco = String(preco).replace('.', ',');`

Comment: Coloquei assim String(preco).replace('.', ',');   ficou  060,50

Comment: Para fazer cálculos você tem que usar com ponto. Após fazer os cálculos você muda para vírgula para exibir.